# Massachusetts Woodland Shapefile / GDB Not Rendering Correctly QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, file-geodatabase, usgs

I am working on a personal project that utilizes USGS Land Cover Woodland data sets and I seem to have an issue in QGIS where part of the state of Massachusetts is missing / not rendering correctly. The first image is what QGIS renders and the second image is the sciencebase.gov thumbnail of the layer. Both the Shapefile and the FileGDB have this issue.

This issue occurs in a new blank QGIS 3.16.3 project with EPSG:4269 projection.

https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5b6fa9f4e4b0f5d57878e73d

https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5b6fa9f3e4b0f5d57878e73b

[image: Massachusetts]

[image: Massachusetts Correct]

Comment: Have your tried to determine if the data is present, but not rendering (which could be a QGIS issue), or is not present (which would be a provider issue)? Either way, it doesn't seem like a problem that GIS SE is organized to address.

Comment: Yes, seems to be a data set / provider issue. The complete USGS Woodland cover FileGDB does not have this issue.

Comment: The data is also available on ftp here ftp://rockyftp.cr.usgs.gov/vdelivery/Datasets/Staged/LndCvr/National/GDB/ (23GB zip file)

Answer (score 1):

Looks to be a data set / provider issue. While not ideal the complete USGS National Woodland Landcover data set does not have this issue.

https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5eae3b7382cefae35a279d6f

[image: Complete Woodlands]